# Adaptors for pointer to member fields

Tags: c++, boost, stl

Is there a STL method/boost class such as:

```
template<class S, class T>
class mem_mem : std::unary_function<T, S>
{
public:
  mem_mem(S T::*_m) : m(_m) {}
  S operator()(T &t) const {
    return t .* m;
  }
  const S operator()(const T &t) const {
    return t .* m;
  }
private:
  S T::*m;
};
```

It is similar to `mem_fun` but for fields.

Comment: What `but I`?. Complete the sentence.

Comment: @Nawaz: Sorry. I just wanted to say that I did some search. To people who voted to close the question: Would you mind to explain why the question is "not a real question"? I tried to read the FAQ several times but I fail to see how the question is "not a real question". For sure it have one definite answer and is on-topic (basically it's question "does C++ standard library have function X and how is it called").

Comment: If you leave the sentence *incomplete*, nobody would understand what you want. That is why it was voted to close the topic. It's so simple to understand, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `boost::bind` or `boost::mem_fn` for this.  If the member passed in is a member to a field, `boost::bind` acts as a functor that returns the data member.

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>


struct X {
  X(): a(0) {};
  X(int i) : a(i) {};


  int a;
};


int main() {

  std::vector<X> v1;
  v1.reserve(10);
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    v1.push_back(X(i));
  }

  std::vector<int> v2(10);
  std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), boost::bind(&X::a, _1));
  // or std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), boost::mem_fn(&X::a));
  std::copy(v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,",") );
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`boost::bind` has [mem_fn](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bind/mem_fn.html) which looks like what you are interested in.